# BigQuery: LAG() on UNNEST()

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was looking at using `LAG()` to return a value from the previous row in an `ARRAY of STRUCT`, and it seems like the navigation window functions like `LAG/LEAD` are not supported with `UNNEST`.

It sounds suboptimal but you need to `UNNEST` all and (re)`PARTITION BY` !!

E.g. say you want the amount of the previous line:

> **EDIT**: Schema details:
>
> Invoices schema : `docID STRING, lines STRUCT<lineID STRING, amount NUMERIC>`
>
> Expected output:  `docID STRING, lines STRUCT<lineID STRING, amount NUMERIC, prev_amount NUMERIC>`

```
SELECT 
   docID, lineID, amount
   ,LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY docID ORDER by lineID) prev_amount
FROM invoices, UNNEST(lines)
```

This is pretty slow. I wish we could somehow pass the ARRAY as window frame to use.

**Any alternative ?** I am using `BigQuery` but this may apply to other DBMS.

> **UPDATE**: I have come up with below alternative using `WITH OFFSET`. Faster and maybe this is what OFFSET is meant to be used for, it's just ugly and could be simpler in my mind.

```
SELECT 
   docID, lineID, amount
   ,(SELECT amount FROM UNNEST(lines) WITH OFFSET AS pos2 WHERE pos2 = pos - 1) prev_amount
FROM invoices, UNNEST(lines) WITH OFFSET AS pos
```

Comment: it is not clear what your expected output! is it same array but with added prev_amount field in struct? if you can provide simplified example of input and output - would be great!

Comment: Sorry - edited ! Output can be flat and I can `ARRAY_AGG` - the challenge is on (best) getting the previous row data. Thanks

Comment: i think my answer is still relevant and is in effect. agree? or should I modify it to match your update (i think you can easily do this )

Comment: Absolutely - love how creative you are ;-). Will wait a bit for other suggestions, and if need be log a feature request as "relative navigation" should be easier within an array.

Comment: Sure. make sense. And I added update to match your update :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below alternative to Mikhail's answer, using `WITH OFFSET` instead, performs better (55s vs. 170s, over 50M rows)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT docID, ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      l.*, 
      lines[SAFE_OFFSET(pos - 1)].amount prev_amount 
    FROM UNNEST(lines) l WITH OFFSET pos
    ) lines
FROM invoices
```

Note: this will not work as-is if `ORDER BY` or a `WHERE` clause is added to the unnesting that changes the original indexing.

This was my use case, and if you are after *relative positioning in an filtered array*, you should use a subquery to create the filtered array first, and then the combination  `UNNEST WITH OFFSET` + `OFFSET/ORDINAL` in the outer query.

Comment: Is with offset equal to posexplode of spark/presto?

Answer (score 1):

Below shows better performance (at least on small amount that I run it against for quick testing). Also execution plan looks much better (to me at least)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
   lines[OFFSET(pos)].*, lines[SAFE_OFFSET(pos - 1)].amount prev_amount
FROM invoices, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, ARRAY_LENGTH(lines) - 1)) pos
```

Note: I was assuming following schema `[STRUCT<docID INT64, lineID INT64, amount FLOAT64>] lines`

> UPDATE: Adjustment to match to real schema you just provided

```
#standardSQL
SELECT docID, ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      lines[OFFSET(pos)].*, 
      lines[SAFE_OFFSET(pos - 1)].amount prev_amount 
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, ARRAY_LENGTH(lines) - 1)) pos
    ) lines
FROM invoices
```